# Using Javascript to pull the url of a hyperlink with a class attribute

Tags: javascript, html

There will be only one link of a particular class on the page.
I'm trying to write a javascript snippet that will find this:

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" class="linkclass"> ... </a>
```

and return a string consisting of this:

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

Thanks in advance everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
var url = (function() {
  var all = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i in all) {
    var cur = all[i];
    if (cur.getAttribute('class') === "linkclass") {
      return cur.getAttribute('href');
    }
  }
  return undefined;
})();
```

Note: If there is only ever one element of that class it would be much more efficient to give the element a unique `id` instead of a `class`.  The code would then be much simpler

```
var url = document.getElementById('theUniqueId').getAttribute('href');
```

Answer (score 2):

If there will be only one instance of a particular class then use an id and grab them with `document.getElementById("linkID").href;`
If you can't do that then using the classes:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var ref = "";
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
{
   if(links[i].className == "linkClass")
   {
      ref = links[i].href;
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't use `===` instead of `==`.  A coercion shouldn't apply here.

Comment: no particular reason. using == or === in this case should result in the same behavior.

Comment: yes. But if it must be a `string` or `undefined` then `===` is more clear on the intent.

Comment: certainly, but not 100% necessary.